# Validating user input from textbox c#

Tags: java, c#, asp.net

I am trying to validate a user input to a given string. I am able to do this in java with this code

```
        String username = request.getParameter("txtUsername");
        String password = request.getParameter("txtPassword"];)

   if (username.equals("john") && (password.equals("smith"))){

        out.println("Success");

    }
    else{

         out.println("validation failed");
     }
```

but it returns a NullReferenceException in C# using this same code.

```
       {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = Request.QueryString["txtUsername"] ?? "";
        String password = Request.QueryString["txtPassword"] ?? "";

        try {
        if(username.Equals("john") && (password.Equals("smith"))){

            lblLogin.Text = "Success";
            Response.Redirect("ModelProfile.aspx");
        }
        else

        {
            lblLogin.Text = "Failed";
             Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

        }
        catch
        {
            lblLogin.Text = "Please type in some valid credentials";

        }

    }
```

Here is the text boxes in the aspx page looks like:

```
            <div id="loginUsername">
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username:"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"   CssClass="mytext"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>

        <div id="loginPassword">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="mytext"></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
        <div id="loginButton">

            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Please any ideas on how I can solve this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Either `username` or `password` is most likely null, as a result of the `Request.QueryString` failing to succeed in finding a match. Put a breakpoint in ans step through - you'll be able to see where it's failing.

Comment: @Baldrick I did and it said username is null. this is clearly not null as i always type in a value

Comment: I would check the casing of `"txtUsername"`. Does that exactly match the request string casing?

Comment: @Baldrick I have had a careful look at my code and I cant find any issues with the casing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily fix your problem with

```
    String username = Request.QueryString["txtUsername"] ?? "";
    String password = Request.QueryString["txtPassword"] ?? "";
```

The ?? is the [C# Null Coalescing operator](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq)

However looking at your code, it seems that you don't have to work with the QueryString because the button login is on the same page of your textboxes. If this is correct then you should reference the textbox directly. No need to check for null because the textbox text property is never null (if you really want to be very precise you could add a Trim)

```
    String username = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
    String password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: This will certainly treat the symptoms, but in his case he actually has a supplied username and password... :)

Comment: Then he has some other part of its code that is wrong. The only thing that comes to mind is a mispelled name

Comment: @Baldrick Yes something like that. In any case, a defensive attitude would suggest to leave the checks in place. You cannot predict the user behavior

Comment: @Steve I have tried that and it did stop the NullReferenceException error. but my code doesn't seem to do anything. it takes the input but doesnt redirect to the requested page. when I did a debug the value of username is null

Comment: @Buzz clearly, something is wrong elsewhere. Not in the code above. You could try to add the code of the Page_Load method of this page and the point where you redirect to this page. Just to have a more comprensive picture of your code.

Comment: @Steve Please see my last edit and don't hesitate if you require more details :) Thanks for your help

Comment: If the button login is on the same page of the txtboxes then why don't you use directly the txtUsername.Text and txtPassword.Text properties? I am not an expert of ASP.NET but here there is no redirection at play. You have just a callback to the same server page.